Proguard: Can't process class [module-info.class]
I am trying to obfuscate my maven project. Below is the section that I added proguard to my pom.xml
`
com.github.wvengen
proguard-maven-plugin
            <executions>
               <execution>
                   <phase>package</phase>
                   <goals><goal>proguard</goal></goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                <injar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</injar>
                <outjar>${project.build.finalName}-final.jar</outjar>
                <inLibFilter>!module-info.class</inLibFilter>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                <proguardInclude>${basedir}/proguard.conf</proguardInclude>
                <libs>
                    
                    <lib>${java.home}/jmods/java.base.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home}/jmods/java.logging.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home}/jmods/java.sql.jmod</lib>
                  </libs>
                <options>
                   
                    <option>
                        

                        -keep class org.cytoscape.CytoCopasi.CyActivator
                        
                    </option>
                   
                </options>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>`

But I am getting the error: Can't process class [module-info.class] (Unsupported version number [67.0] (maximum 65.65535, Java null))
When I try to exclude module-info.class as follows: ${java.home}/jmods/java.base.jmod(!**.jar;!module-info.class) in lib, it perceives that as the full file path.
I also tried the following : !module-info.class, but to no avail.
I am not sure what I am missing. Could you please assist?
using proguard version 7.4.1
java version is jdk-23
Thanks in advance

It looks like you are mixing JDK21 preview with JDK23. Code built for a particular JDK in preview mode is not usually compatible with any other JDK.

I see. So must I work with an older JDK version?

It's not clear - the error message suggests that you aren't running JDK23, but maybe using JDK21 preview mode. Check your environment for which JDK built which jar, and which one you are really using for the build.
